# Send data(score) from unity game to android application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have made an android app that includes a game module, I have made game using unity. Now I want to get game score back into my android application when user finish the game. I am starting game using an implicit intent.

Here is how i am starting game. `startNewActivity(GameClubMediaIntro.this,"com.flieskiller");`

```
  public void startNewActivity(Context context, String packageName) {
        Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (intent == null) {
            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

On game finished i need its score back into my android app. I have gone through this question, [Read Android intent extra data on Unity app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098400/read-android-intent-extra-data-on-unity-app-launch)  But it doesn't tell how to channel data back to app.

Comment: How about you send your score to a server and your app fetches the score from the server. It would be much more maintainable.

Comment: But it should not be recommendable. As there might be network issue. I want to avoid network overhead. Is there some file system available in unity to store score which would be accessible to my android app

Comment: @SouravKanta I am resuming my app immediately after game closes.